# How to reinitialize scripts inside django admin when new inline object is added?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models with foreign key relationship. Inside admin panel one of them displays like inline object and has a `django-leaflet` map inside. Inlines added with `'Add another'` button have empty input instead of a map.

So i need to initialize scripts again, how would i do that? Thanks!

Comment: What scripts do you mean?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I mean [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet) js scripts. My goal is to display a map instead of input in newly added inline object. Thanks for helping!